# php error installing imagick

Tags: php, linux, centos7, imagick

**System - CentOS 7.5.1804**

**PHP Version - 7.0.3**

So, I'm trying to install Imagick in order to be able to render/make an image off the first page of a PDF.

I'm tried to understand how it is setup, but I'm missing something, so I'll reproduce what I've and what I've got so far:

After a long list of errors, I got down to these 4 instalations:

```
sudo rpm -Uvh ImageMagick-7.0.8-9.x86_64.rpm
sudo rpm -Uvh ImageMagick-libs-7.0.8-9.x86_64.rpm 
sudo yum install php70-php-pecl-imagick.x86_64
sudo php go-pear.phar
```

When I'm trying to run this: `sudo /usr/bin/pecl install imagick`, it's giving me the following error:

> WARNING: channel "pecl.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pecl channel-update pecl.php.net" to update
>   downloading imagick-3.4.3.tgz ...
>   Starting to download imagick-3.4.3.tgz (245,410 bytes)
>   ............................................done: 245,410 bytes
>   19 source files, building
>   running: phpize
>   Can't find PHP headers in /usr/include/php
>   The php-devel package is required for use of this command.
>   ERROR: `phpize' failed

So, after checking that 'php-devel' is somewhat not here, I try to install it and I get this:

> Error: Package: php-pecl-jsonc-devel-1.3.10-2.el7.remi.5.6.x86_64 (remi-php56)
>                  Requires: php-pecl-jsonc(x86-64) = 1.3.10-2.el7.remi.5.6
>                  Available: php-pecl-jsonc-1.3.10-1.el7.remi.5.6.x86_64 (remi-php56)
>                      php-pecl-jsonc(x86-64) = 1.3.10-1.el7.remi.5.6
>
> Error: Package: php-pecl-jsonc-1.3.10-2.el7.remi.5.6.x86_64 (remi-php56)
>
> Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64
>
> Installed: php-common-7.0.31-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php70)
>                      php(zend-abi) = 20151012-64
>   Available: php-common-5.4.16-45.el7.x86_64 (base)
>                      php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
>   Available: php-common-5.6.36-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
>                      php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64
>   Available: php-common-5.6.37-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
>                      php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64
>
> Error: Package: php-devel-5.6.37-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
>
> Requires: php-cli(x86-64) = 5.6.37-1.el7.remi
>
> Installed: php-cli-7.0.31-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php70)
>                      php-cli(x86-64) = 7.0.31-1.el7.remi
>   Available: php-cli-5.4.16-45.el7.x86_64 (base)
>                      php-cli(x86-64) = 5.4.16-45.el7
>   Available: php-cli-5.6.36-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
>                      php-cli(x86-64) = 5.6.36-1.el7.remi
>   Available: php-cli-5.6.37-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
>                      php-cli(x86-64) = 5.6.37-1.el7.remi
>
> Error: Package: php-pecl-jsonc-1.3.10-2.el7.remi.5.6.x86_64 (remi-php56)
>
> Requires: php(api) = 20131106-64
>
> Installed: php-common-7.0.31-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php70)
>                      php(api) = 20151012-64
>   Available: php-common-5.4.16-45.el7.x86_64 (base)
>                      php(api) = 20100412-64
>   Available: php-common-5.6.36-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
>                      php(api) = 20131106-64
>   Available: php-common-5.6.37-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
>                      php(api) = 20131106-64

What am I doing wrong/what am I missing?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

you can use remi php repositories to easily install and maintain your server.

first download the remi-release rpm file from address below :

`http://remi.schlundtech.de/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm`

then, run :

`sudo rpm -Uvh remi-release-7.rpm`

edit file `remi.repo` : `sudo vim /etc/yum.repos.d` and make sure that the value of `enabled` in section `[remi]` is `1`.

```
[remi]
#some configurations
enabled=1
```

now with this command you can install every version of php with any extention you need.

`sudo yum install php70-php php70-php-imagick`

Comment: I've got those installed and the problem remains. What can I do to be able to use Imagick?

Comment: go to directory `/etc/yum.repos.d` and check the result of `ls` command, tell me about list that you see.

Comment: have you enabled `remi` repo in `remi.repo` file ?

Answer (score 0):

For me running

```
yum install ImageMagick ImageMagick-devel
```

and then running

```
pecl install imagick
```

solved the issue. I'm using CentOS 7 server.